# Is it possible to embed a UINavigationView to a UIView

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I have started developing iOS apps programmatically without using storyboards or any nibs, pure coding.

I wanted to do a popping out menu like the ones you press on a navigation bar and it displays the information with an animation, the solution I have thought is adding two subviews of type UIView to my main view controller, and then embed a tableView and a UINavigationView to those two UIViews, I got the constraints and the action of deploying the menu, its just a matter of embedding the other elements to complete my task.

My question is, what is the function I should be looking for? 
I have no idea how to address this problem, its pretty basic but as is programmatically there are not many things that I found out there, usually they just right away answer or put the code but I want to understand the logic behind it.
I know there are libraries but I actually believe is better to understand how to do it and develop my own version of it.

I already tried to add a UINavigationController as a subview of my UIView and it says that this UINavigation is not a type of UIView, I understand the point and it actually make sense but still I haven't found anything useful to implement as code

Any help from you guys would be appreciated, I am open to suggestions and if you know a better way to do this task or you know where should I be looking to solve this question please just let me know it as I am a beginner in iOS developing.

This is my main idea

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it will help you**

```
let sideRoot = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sideRoot") as! SideRootViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sideRoot)
self.addChildViewController(navController)
sideView.addSuview(navController.view)
```

Comment: Hi Musavir, thanks for your help, one question that comes to my mind after reading your code is that the sideRoot that you propose is using a storyboard and as I mentioned I am not using any storyboards what I am doing is 100% programmatically.

Comment: then is it possible to do something like this?
let sideRoot  = UINavigationController() as! SideRootViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootviewController: sideRoot)
self.addChildViewController(navController)
sideView.addSubbview(navController.view)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,First thing you can use any view and add as subview with animation.
>   You can use any animation you want for menu UIView.
>   in your case you can use Transition in CGAffineTransform
>   Before presenting view add transform your view like :

```
childView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
```

//values are 0,0 here you can changes as per you need then you can animate as :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        childView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: parentView.frame.maxX, y: 0)
    })
```

//Where child view is your menu view which contains views for informations including table view.

//Here also you can change values according to your need.
//let me know if it helps or if you need to ask something.